# SQLite Save Error NOT NULL Constraint

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a local database in my app for storing user profiles from input fields. I have created the database using SQLiteOpenHelper class but after running my app, this error appears. I have been through the DatabaseHelper class but can't find what's wrong with it. I hope someone points out my mistake. Thanks.

my db class file here:

```
public class DBHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UsersDemo.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "profileInfo";

private static final String COL_ID = "databaseId";
public static final String COL_USER_ID = "userId";
public static final String COL_FULL_NAME = "fullName";
public static final String COL_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String COL_DOB = "DOB";
public static final String COL_MOBILE_NUM = "mobileNum";
public static final String COL_OCCUPATION = "occupation";
public static final String COL_ORGANIZATION = "organization";
//private static final String COL_PROFILE_PHOTO = "profilePhoto";

private Context mCtx;

private DatabaseManager databaseManager;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBHelper(Context context){
    this.mCtx = context;
    databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(mCtx);
}

public DBHelper open() throws SQLException{
    db = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    databaseManager.close();
}

public boolean saveInputField(TingTingUser user){
    SQLiteDatabase userDb = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COL_FULL_NAME, user.getDisplayName());
    values.put(COL_USER_ID, user.getUserId());
    values.put(COL_GENDER, user.getGender());
    values.put(COL_DOB, user.getDob());
    values.put(COL_MOBILE_NUM, user.getMobileNumber());
    values.put(COL_ORGANIZATION, user.getOrganization());
    values.put(COL_OCCUPATION, user.getOccupation());

    long result = userDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    userDb.close();

    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

public TingTingUser getCurrentUser(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase currDB = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = currDB.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COL_ID, COL_USER_ID, COL_FULL_NAME, COL_GENDER, COL_DOB, COL_MOBILE_NUM, COL_OCCUPATION, COL_ORGANIZATION}, COL_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
        TingTingUser user = new TingTingUser(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7));
        return user;
    }

    return null;

}

public void saveCameraImage(byte[] imageBytes){
    SQLiteDatabase camDb = databaseManager.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    //contentValues.put(COL_PROFILE_PHOTO, imageBytes);
    camDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public void saveGalleryImage(byte[] imageBytes){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    //contentValues.put(COL_PROFILE_PHOTO, imageBytes);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String db_create = "Create Table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + COL_USER_ID + " TEXT, "
                + COL_FULL_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + COL_GENDER + " TEXT, "
                + COL_DOB + " TEXT, "
                + COL_MOBILE_NUM + " TEXT, "
                + COL_OCCUPATION + " TEXT, "
                + COL_ORGANIZATION + " TEXT, ";
                //+ COL_PROFILE_PHOTO + " BLOB NOT NULL );";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(db_create);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

}

}
```

The error occurs in my MainActivity when I call saveInputField() method of DBHelper, shown below:

```
JsonObjectRequest otpObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.TING_VERIFY_OTP_ENDPOINT, verifyOTPObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("OTPDialogFragment", "OTP Verification Response is: \t" + response.toString());
                Log.d("OTPDialogFragment", "OTP Verified Successfully");

                try {
                    JSONObject verifyObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    JSONObject userObject = verifyObject.getJSONObject("user");

                    userId = userObject.getString("_id");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved user id is:\t" + userId);

                    TingTingUser user = new TingTingUser();
                    user.setDisplayName(fullName);
                    user.setMobileNumber(num);
                    user.setGender(genderVal);
                    user.setDob(dob);
                    user.setOccupation("default");
                    user.setOrganization("default");
                    user.setUserId(userId);

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fullName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(genderVal) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(dob) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)){
                        if (dbHelper.saveInputField(user) == true){  // error occurs here
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Saved User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Save Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // Toast shows cos save failed, dont know why
                        }
                    }
```

Sorry guys, my mainactivity is too long, only showed what is necessary.

Error message in logcat:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Create Table profileInfo (databaseId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, userId TEXT, fullName TEXT, gender TEXT, DOB TEXT, mobileNum TEXT, occupation TEXT, organization TEXT,
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                 at com.billionusers.tingting.db.DBHelper$DatabaseManager.onCreate(DBHelper.java:131)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                 at com.billionusers.tingting.db.DBHelper.saveInputField(DBHelper.java:53)
                                                 at com.billionusers.tingting.activities.SignUpActivity$OTPDialogFragment$6.onResponse(SignUpActivity.java:466)
                                                 at com.billionusers.tingting.activities.SignUpActivity$OTPDialogFragment$6.onResponse(SignUpActivity.java:443)
                                                 at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
                                                 at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logcat

```
near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Create Table profileInfo (databaseId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, userId TEXT, fullName TEXT, gender TEXT, DOB TEXT, mobileNum TEXT, occupation TEXT, organization TEXT,
```

and `DBHelper.onCreate`

```
String db_create = "Create Table " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COL_USER_ID + " TEXT, "
            + COL_FULL_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + COL_GENDER + " TEXT, "
            + COL_DOB + " TEXT, "
            + COL_MOBILE_NUM + " TEXT, "
            + COL_OCCUPATION + " TEXT, "
            + COL_ORGANIZATION + " TEXT, ";
            //+ COL_PROFILE_PHOTO + " BLOB NOT NULL );";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(db_create);
```

Your create statement is invalid because you have put into comments the last line so it terminates in `+ COL_ORGANIZATION + " TEXT, ";` which is not correct. The ending should be:

```
+ COL_ORGANIZATION + " TEXT ); ";
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to restrict sqlite database to have only one row?

Comment: Can't understand what you mean, can you please rephrase?

Comment: I want to have only one row in database when created. Tell me how?

Comment: What do you mean "one row in database when created". 1)The create script, creates the database table, it does not insert any rows, it is completely empty, you have to insert rows with `insert` statements. 2) A database table can contain many **rows** why you want to limit this to one?